# Convert Day of Year to Calendar Month during a leap year in Excel

Tags: excel, date, leap-year

```
Year    Day          Time           TimeStamp
2008    60    3/1    2400    0:00   03/01/2008 00:00
```

I'm converting DOY to regular calendar month but since 2008 was a leap year the formula I was using for non-leap years does not work. I tried subtracting the formula by 1 but it still gives me the wrong date. Day 60 in 2008 is 02/29/2008.

`=A1+41274` for non-leap years (this yields 03/01/2008).

`=A1+41273` tried this for the leap year (this yields 02/28/2008).

Answer (score 1):

Excel already has a formula to find the date when the day number and an year is mentioned
DATE(Year,1,day) This returns the date
In your case it is,
DATE(2008,1,60) This returns 29/02/2008

Comment: That works great, thank you. I do need to keep the year format as 2008 instead of 08. How can I do that while still using this function?